# Basically I believe I am trying to Sum a Sum in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am struggling with a Crystal 10 report.  What I need to be able to do is interrogate all of the lines in an order and if I find an order that contains a key line or element (Frame), then I want to capture the sale price of the entire order and write it to a running total field to be reported in the footer of the report.
Example:
In the 1st order I have two line items; one is a Frame and the other is also a Frame. Because the order contains at least one frame,  I want to record the total from the order to a running total field calculation..  The total of this invoice is $50.00.
In the 2nd order I have two Mats. Because the order does not contain a Frame then this order does not qualify.
In the 3rd and final order, I have two Mats & a Frame therefore this order would qualify. The total amount for this order is $75 so I would add it to the running total calculation.
The end result is I should have a “Grand” running total of $125.00. 
My problem is that whatever I try, the formulas I am using handles the 1st order correctly, the 2nd correctly but because there is a Mat in the 3rd order, it ignores the 3rd order all together and it shouldn't. 
Please help….

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain what you have tried?

It is going to be a bit tricky, and I would probably try and do it closer to the source. What is your datasource?

You will take a bit of a performance hit but you could add a sql expression something like:

`(select count(*) from mytable where ordern_number = "table.order_number" and product = 'frame') as includes_frame`

Then you can do a running total on your amount column and tell crystal to evaluate where `{includes_frame} > 0`